# Error when create a new project in Cocos2dx version 3.0 final

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

When I create a new project in Cocos2dx 3.0 (final), I got this issue.

[image]

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was answered here: http://cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/52510 as you posted for help in both places.